# Can you manipulate the legend or integrate the generated legend in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to have a legend for my pie/doughnut charts in ChartJS that I can manipulate.

Obviously being in canvas complicates this and I see no documentation for moving the legend from the top or bottom or manipulating some of its styles.

It does have a "generateLegend()" method available, which creates the legend in HTML, but then it is no longer connected to all the functionality of ChartJS.

What I'm trying to accomplish is a legend to the right of my pie or doughnut chart that is able to filter out the label clicked in the legend, like it normally does in the default legend. So for instance if the chart is of "icecreams" and in the legend I click "chocolate", it will animate out the chocolate from the chart. It would also be nice to attach the values to the legend.

So it would be like this picture:

[image]

The important part is being able to filter out parts of the chart that correlate with the label clicked on the legend.

Been researching and messing with it all day. Canvas may just make it too difficult.

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration (The **generateLabels** option is what you need)

Comment: @AlonEitan Do you mind explaining further? The more details link on that is broken and it's not clear to me what that does or how to use it.

Comment: To implement your own legend and hide the native chartjs legend: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2565